# Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Here i am creating Vm using docker-machine but getting error. I did all the solution availabe on the internet but still can't resolve the error.
[here the screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp5Lx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create `/etc/vbox/networks.conf` with the following contents:

```
* 192.168.99.1/24
```

In my research, found useful these links in the issues of the repository of kubernetes/minikube on Github posts by [laundry-96](https://github.com/laundry-96) on [#12764](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12764) that leads to [jhcookby](https://github.com/jhcookby) on [#12765](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12765).

That finally will get you to the [virtualbox manual network hosts only](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) where you can read more about it.